# Issues with presenting UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9

I am having issues w/rendering UIActivityViewController.
Using the following code:

```
let objectsToShare: NSArray = ["test", "http://www.test.com"];
let activityVC: UIActivityViewController  = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

renders the following ActivityViewController:

[image]

Anyone has faced similar issue and knows a workaround?

Also, sometimes the rendering issue becomes even worse:

[image]

Comment: What does `self` refer to? (What controller are you presenting it from?)

Comment: I am presenting it from UIViewController